# cardinality of the set of points with one irrational coordinate, and one rational.

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, cardinals

> Find the cardinality of the set of all points in the plane which have one rational and one irrational coordinate. Justify you answer.

My thoughts so far. We know that $\mathbb Q$, the set of all rational numbers, has a cardinality of  $\aleph_0$. Also, since the set of irrational numbers is just the reals with the rationals removed, thus the set of irrational numbers has a cardinality of $\mathfrak c$ (continuum). Therefore, it seems logical to conclude that the ordered pair also has a cardinality of $\mathfrak c$.

I'm fairly sure this would justify the answer. However, is there a way to prove this using either a bijection or the Cantor-Bernstein theorem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: "an ordered pair" is not the correct expression in your context. You are talking about a set of ordered pairs, not just one ordered pair. Each ordered pair $\langle x,y\rangle$ usually represented ([following Kuratowski](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_pair#Kuratowski_definition)) as $\{\{x\},\{x,y\}\}$ has cardinality $2$ (or $1$, if $x=y$). The current title "*Cardinality of an ordered pair*" is misleading, a more suitable one might be "*Cardinality of the set of points with one irrational coordinate*"

Comment: Valid point, I took that into account now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would prove it as follows:

Let $A$ denote your set of points, and let $B=\{(0,x)\ |\ x\text{ irrational }\}$.

Then $B\subset A$, and $|B|=\mathfrak c$ (there is a bijection from the irrationals to $B$ given by $x\mapsto (0,x)$). Thus $\mathfrak c\leq |A|$.

Since $\mathbb{R}^2$ has the cardinality of the continuum, and since $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2$, we have also $|A|\leq \mathfrak c$. In total $|A|=\mathfrak c$.

Comment: Nice job! I would've never thought to construct a B that is contained within A. Thank you for your help.